# 3 x regulator 7805 for the same source

Tags: voltage-regulator

So in my project I need to have 3 outputs that has 5v ( with each at least 1,5A)  and one output that has 9v, so I though what if I bring one 9v source voltage with like 5A and put 3 regulators 7805 so I will have a circuits like this : [image]

Note that the regulators **are not in parallel** as each will supply a part in my project, so I wonder if I may have any problem using this circuit? if so how can I solve my poblem.

Comment: Hi Müller, Thanks for your reply, may I ask you?

Comment: each passing *more than 1.5A ?* You may run afoul of the internal shutdown due to over-temperature unless you provide considerable heat sink to each.

Comment: Yes for each I will use a heat sink, and the 1,5A is a peak value, I don't need it all the time just once per minute or maybe more.

Comment: How much total max current you draw from you 9V + 3x 5V?

Comment: about 5A peak (1,5A for each 5V and 500ma for the 9V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inherent problem in using the same source for several regulators.

One aspect might require attention- if the individual parts of your project communicate with each other via logic signals, say, then if there is, say during power up or power  down, more than a few hundred millivolts difference between the outputs then there could be issues. Using the same part types from the same supplier reduces the likelihood of that.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your reply, actually, the 9v goes for an arduino board+shield and the other 5v goes for servos,acutators, I use arduino's PWM to control them.